# Mysql doesn't work after installing both through brew and the package from the official website

Tags: mysql, homebrew, macos-sierra, failed-installation

```
Shans-Macbook:~ Shanshan$  sudo cp /usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-small.cnf /etc/my.cnf

Password:

cp: /usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-small.cnf: No such file or directory



Shans-Macbook:~ Shanshan$  sudo cd /usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-small.cnf /etc/my.cnf

/usr/bin/cd: line 4: cd: /usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-small.cnf: No such file or directory

Shans-Macbook:~ Shanshan$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start

Starting MySQL
.................................................................................................... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Shans-Macbook.pid).


Shans-Macbook:~ Shanshan$ mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

[1] 15852

Shans-Macbook:~ Shanshan$ 2017-03-31T07:16:22.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/Shans-Macbook.err'.

2017-03-31T07:16:22.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/Shans-Macbook.err'.

/usr/local/bin/mysqld_safe: line 139: /usr/local/var/mysql/Shans-Macbook.err: Permission denied

2017-03-31T07:16:22.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql

/usr/local/bin/mysqld_safe: line 139: /usr/local/var/mysql/Shans-Macbook.err: Permission denied

/usr/local/bin/mysqld_safe: line 193: /usr/local/var/mysql/Shans-Macbook.err: Permission denied

2017-03-31T07:16:22.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Shans-Macbook.pid ended
/usr/local/bin/mysqld_safe: line 139: /usr/local/var/mysql/Shans-Macbook.err: Permission denied



Shans-Macbook:~ Shanshan$ mysql -u root

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
[1]+  Done                    mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables



Shans-Macbook:~ Shanshan$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL

./usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/bin/mysqld_safe: line 139: 

/usr/local/var/mysql/Shans-Macbook.err: Permission denied

/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/bin/mysqld_safe: line 139: 

/usr/local/var/mysql/Shans-Macbook.err: Permission denied

/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/bin/mysqld_safe: line 193: 

/usr/local/var/mysql/Shans-Macbook.err: Permission denied

/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/bin/mysqld_safe: line 139: 

/usr/local/var/mysql/Shans-Macbook.err: Permission denied

 ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Shans-Macbook.pid).
```

I have spend 2 days searching and trying every post online, and it is still not working.

My mac's system is macOS Sierra.

```
Shans-Macbook:~ Shanshan$ mysql -V

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for osx10.12 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: The error would be a good place to start - [are any of these](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mysql+The+server+quit+without+updating+PID+file) helpful?

Answer (score -1):

I think you wan't the MySQL workbench. 
If you download the DMG File: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Then you probably need the Server as well:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Check it out, there are a lot of forums, wich provide this problem.

Comment: The OP specifically wants to use Homebrew, and your answer does not reply to that. Are you able to help on that point?

Comment: I used Homebrew. It installed mysql without password, so I can open it from the mysqlworkbench, but it is still not working through terminal.